# Create HttpRequestMessage or HttpResponse message from http file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to create a HttpRequestMessage or HttpResponseMessage from .http files? Visual Studio has the test feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/http-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0 to do this.  I use [mockhttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) for unit tests. It would be useful to the ability to use create HttpRequestMessage or HttpResponseMessage from the .http file to build the various test cases. Since the tooling supports it, there must be code out there that does this.

Comment: I looked into it a while ago, and the way `HttpClient` parses `HttpResponseMessage` is heavily tied to the tcp / ssl stream handling. (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3296daea97f517709ec428320340e77283b5cb4d/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs#L630)